# Inherit multiple times from same base object with different Generics

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I have an `Object` class in my library implementing event logic for a given set of events with type hints:

```py
class Event(enum.Enum):
    pass

EventT = TypeVar("EventT", bound=Event)

class Object(Generic[EventT]):
    def bind(self, event: EventT, callback): ...
    def fire(self, event: EventT): ...
```

I then have a `Container` class who inherits from `Object`:

```
class ContainerEvent(Event):
    ITEM_ADDED = auto()
    ITEM_REMOVED = auto()

ContainedT = TypeVar("ContainedT")

class Container(Generic[ContainedT], Object[ContainerEvent]):
    def add(self, item_id, item: ContainedT): ...
    def get(self, item_id) -> ContainedT: ...
    def remove(self, item_id): ...
```

Let's say I want to add an `Application` class. It's a `Window` `Container`, but also an `Object` with its own `Event`s.

```py
class ApplicationEvent(Event):
    START = auto()

class Application(Container[Window], Object[ApplicationEvent]):
    def start():
        self.fire(ApplicationEvent.START)
```

However, this fails since both `Application` and `Container` inherit from `Object`:

> ```
> Base classes of Application are mutually incompatible
>   Base class "Object[ApplicationEvent]" is incompatible with type "Object[ContainerEvent]"
> ```

How can I make `Application` be both a `Container` and an `Object`? Without type hints, I can inherit one time from `Object`, so how can I do it with type hinting?

Comment: Please note `mypy` doesn't report anything with this code.

Comment: Is an application a *kind* of container, or does it *have*  a container? You are probably using inheritance where you should be using composition.

Comment: Thanks @chepner , I should probably make a `container` attribute. Still, I would like `Application` to be a kind of `Container`, since `Application.add("my_window", window)` looks better than `Application.container.add("my_window", window)`.

Comment: You can define `Application.add_window` that acts as a wrapper around `Container.add`.

Comment: Inheritance does not get used as often as most language tutorials would lead you to believe.

Comment: I used inheritence as it seems logic: an application is a window container, but it's also an object (with events). If it isn't possible, I'll try with composition. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you think about this line carefully: `self.fire(ApplicationEvent.START)`, is this compatible with an `Object[ContainerEvent]`? If it isn't, then your event subclasses aren't compatible, and having `Application` inheriting from `Object[ContainerEvent]` (implicitly, via `Container[Window]`) doesn't make sense.

Comment: An `Application` is a `Container`. That means you can fire `ContainerEvent` from it. It also has its own events, `ApplicationEvent`. You can use both `ContainerEvent` and `ApplicationEvent` on an `Application` then.